# Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.2.1

Tags: android, firebase

**My SDK manager says everything is upto date:**
Google Play Services: 33
Google Repository: 35

**build.gradle content:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.project.cloudmessagingdemo"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.2.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Why doesn't this compile?

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qx2Fc.png)

Comment: Please post the full error log and entire build.gradle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Repository 35 contains the latest version - try `'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.6.1'`.

Unfortunately 9.6.1 was a patch release put out late last week, so not all of the documentation may be updated to point to it quite yet - sorry!

Comment: To check - is Android Studio using the same SDK location as the SDK manager that you checked was updated to Google Repository version 35? Any chance it could be referring to another one?

Answer (score 1):

Update your Google Repository in your SDK.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

File name 
build.gradle(Project:"Your app name")

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
}
```

Add that line "classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0' " into build.gradle file in your project

Comment: could change compile version and build version (Eg.                     compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion "24.0.2") in build.gradle(Modle: app)

Comment: that above one is latest and could please check once more in your code. and refer below link https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases#may_2016_-_v90

Comment: I am using same dependencies:                                                         dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'com.paypal.sdk:paypal-android-sdk:2.14.4'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.6.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.6.1'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.15.0'
}

Answer (score 0):

**Degrade the firebase version**.Worked for me